# Error while generating number sequence for a dataframe of vectors

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below table for which I am generating a sequence of numbers with `rowId` column in order to perform a join but this is throwing the following error. What am I doing wrong? Please help me with this.

```
fListVec: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: vector]
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[2.5046410000000003,2.1487149999999997,1.0884870000000002,3.5877090000000003]|
|[0.9558040000000001,0.9843780000000002,0.545025,0.9979860000000002]          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val fListrdd = fListVec.rdd
    .map{case Row(features: Vector) => features}
    .zipWithIndex()
    .toDF("features","rowId")    

fListrdd.createOrReplaceTempView("featuresTable")
val f = spark.sql("SELECT features, rowId from featuresTable")
f.show(false)
```

Output:

> import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
>       import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
>       org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 206.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 206.0 (TID 1718, localhost, executor driver): scala.MatchError:
>   [[2.5046410000000003,2.1487149999999997,1.0884870000000002,3.5877090000000003]]
>   (of class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
>         at $$$$4896e3e877b134a87d9ee46b238e22$$$$$anonfun$1.apply(:193)
>         at $$$$4896e3e877b134a87d9ee46b238e22$$$$$anonfun$1.apply(:193)
>         at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1762)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedWithIndexRDD$$anonfun$2.apply(ZippedWithIndexRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedWithIndexRDD$$anonfun$2.apply(ZippedWithIndexRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Driver stacktrace:
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>         at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedWithIndexRDD.(ZippedWithIndexRDD.scala:50)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$zipWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:1293)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$zipWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:1293)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.zipWithIndex(RDD.scala:1292)
>         ... 101 elided
>       Caused by: scala.MatchError: [[2.5046410000000003,2.1487149999999997,1.0884870000000002,3.5877090000000003]]
>   (of class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
>         at $$$$4896e3e877b134a87d9ee46b238e22$$$$$anonfun$1.apply(:193)
>         at $$$$4896e3e877b134a87d9ee46b238e22$$$$$anonfun$1.apply(:193)
>         at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1762)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedWithIndexRDD$$anonfun$2.apply(ZippedWithIndexRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedWithIndexRDD$$anonfun$2.apply(ZippedWithIndexRDD.scala:52)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>         ... 3 more

Expected Output:

```
 features                 |       rowId

[2.5046410000000003,...]            0
[0.9558040000000001,...]            1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write a `map` function in the middle to define the *dataType* for the new `dataframe` to be created as

```
val fListrdd = fListVec.rdd
  .map{case Row(features) => features}
  .zipWithIndex()
  .map(x => (x._1.asInstanceOf[DenseVector], x._2.toInt))
  .toDF("features","rowId")
```

where `.map(x => (x._1.asInstanceOf[DenseVector], x._2.toInt))` line is only added.

You can go one step further and create a `dataset`. I personally recommend `dataset` as **datasets are type safety and optimized form of dataframes**.

For that you would need a `case class`

```
case class features(features: DenseVector, rowId: Int)
```

and just add `features` word in my above solution, so that you can call `.toDS` api to create a *type-safety* `dataset`.

```
val fListDS = fListVec.rdd
  .map{case Row(features: DenseVector) => features}
  .zipWithIndex()
  .map(x => features(x._1.asInstanceOf[DenseVector], x._2.toInt))
  .toDS
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there - just need to specify the proper vector type `DenseVector`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val fList = Seq(
  (Seq(2.5046410000000003, 2.1487149999999997, 1.0884870000000002, 3.5877090000000003)),
  (Seq(0.9558040000000001, 0.9843780000000002, 0.545025, 0.9979860000000002))
).toDF("features")

def seqToVec = udf(
  (s: Seq[Double]) => new DenseVector(s.toArray)
)

val fListVec = fList.withColumn("features", seqToVec($"features"))
// fListVec: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: vector]

val fListrdd = fListVec.rdd.
  map{ case Row(features: DenseVector) => features }.
  zipWithIndex.
  toDF("features", "rowId")  

fListrdd.show
// +--------------------+-----+
// |            features|rowId|
// +--------------------+-----+
// |[2.50464100000000...|    0|
// |[0.95580400000000...|    1|
// +--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: This gave me an error which got resolved when I added the map function that Ramesh specified. Thanks for taking time to respond.

Comment: You shouldn't need the additional `map` since the first one already hints the vector type.  I've expanded the answer to provide a complete example.